# How do I fix this loop validation?

Tags: java, validation, while-loop

I am VERY new to Java, I am trying to do a unit conversion program from Fahrenheit to Celsius and I am stun on the validation loop. This is what I got.

```
    // Validation
    do {
        isNumber = true;

        System.out.print("What is the temperature in Fahrenheit?: ");

        // If alphabetical characters are entered
        while (!input.hasNextDouble()) {
            System.out.println("Oops! Try entering only numerical characters.");
            System.out.println();

            isNumber = false;
            input.next();
        }
        fahrenheit = input.nextDouble();

    } while (!isNumber);
```

as you can see what I am trying to validate is that the user doesn't enter a string. but when I run the program it gets stuck on some sort of loop and it says

```
    What is the temperature in Fahrenheit?: something <-- what I input
    Oops! Try entering only numerical characters.
```

and that's it. it doesn't go back to the the input or anything, it just stays there until I enter a number and then it goes back to

```
    What is the temperature in Fahrenheit?:
```

To clarify, my problem is only with the validation loop, because when I enter a number it works just fine. The problem ONLY appears when I enter a string.

Comment: `input.nextLineDouble();` ? That doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuickTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double fahrenheit;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Validation
        while(true) {

            System.out.print("What is the temperature in Fahrenheit?: ");

            // If alphabetical characters are entered
            if (!input.hasNextDouble()) {
                System.out.println("Oops! " +
                        "Try entering only numerical characters.\n");

                // Clear away erroneous input
                input.nextLine();
            }
            else {

                fahrenheit = input.nextDouble();
                break; // Get out of while loop
            }
        }

        input.close();
        System.out.println("Temperature in Fahrenheit: " + fahrenheit);
    }
}
```

**Input/Output:**

```
What is the temperature in Fahrenheit?: abc
Oops! Try entering only numerical characters.

What is the temperature in Fahrenheit?: banana
Oops! Try entering only numerical characters.

What is the temperature in Fahrenheit?: 36.5
Temperature in Fahrenheit: 36.5
```

**Note:**

- Revised the code. You do not need a while loop within a do-while loop.
- Check if the input is a double, break out of while loop if it is indeed a double value.

Comment: Gosu, I still have the same problem.

Comment: if I do `fahrenheit = input.nextDouble();
            isNumber = true; // Set this to true!!` the `isNumber` will never be `false` and the `while (!isNumber);` becomes obsolete

Comment: I allready made `isNumber = true;` at the beginning of the `do {` loop

Comment: @lokilindo okay, you don't need `isNumber`.. Just break out of the enclosing loop that prompts for input once you get a double value.

Comment: Thank you very much, the it worked after the edit. I've spend about 3 hours trying to work around this.

Comment: @lokilindo You can accept it as the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double fahrenheit;

    do  {
        System.out.print("What is the temperature in Fahrenheit?: ");
        try  {
            fahrenheit = input.nextDouble();
            //Do your work
            break;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Oops! Try entering only numerical characters.");
            System.out.println();
        }
    } while (true);
```

Answer (score 0):

this will do the trick.

```
public class Main
{

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.print( "What is the temperature in Fahrenheit?: " );

        // If alphabetical characters are entered
        while ( !input.hasNextDouble() )
        {
            System.out.println( "Oops! Try entering only numerical characters." );
            System.out.println();

            input.next();
        }
        //Do Fahrenheit to Celsius calculation

    }

}
```